# Symmetries of MCG in terms of Humphries generators?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

The Riemann-Hurwitz formula gives $84(g-1)$ as the upper bound to the order of a finite group acting faithfully on a closed genus g surface.  Famously the bound is realized when $g=3$ by a simple group of order $168$. This realizes some symmetry on the mapping class group of the surface. I was looking for references that show how to write this action in terms of the Humphries generators.

Comment: You mean you want to find generators for the maximal-rank finite subgroup of the genus $3$ mapping class group, expressed using the Humphries generators?  Expressing any given finite-order mapping class as a product of Dehn twists (much less the Humphries generators) is extremely messy, and I can't imagine it really revealing anything.  It'll just be a bunch of giant formulas.  Is there some application you have in mind?

Comment: @AndyPutman Sorry, to clarify, I would like to see formulas for the generators of the finite simple group written out in Humphries generators.  Also, I don’t plan to _look_ at these generators, but put them into a computer program.